# Why does this Javascript API fail?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Trying to upload a file to Google Drive via the Drive API. But for some reason, the code underneath only uploads a text file, containing the body elements, instead of a real video.

[image: image of the text file that is uploaded]

The code can be found underneath (Javascript Fetch - made with Postman)

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "mp4/video");
myHeaders.append("Content-Length", "933233");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer access token");

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "[PROXY]");
formdata.append("name", "filenameyo");
formdata.append("mimeType", "mp4/video");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Just paste in the text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads):

> - Simple upload (uploadType=media). Use this upload type to quickly transfer a small media file (5 MB or less) without supplying metadata.
>   To perform a simple upload, refer to Perform a simple upload.
> - Multipart upload (uploadType=multipart). Use this upload type to quickly transfer a small file (5 MB or less) and metadata that
>   describes the file, in a single request. To perform a multipart
>   upload, refer to Perform a multipart upload.

You said `uploadType=media` so the API expects you to send **just a file**

However you are sending a FormData object with the file and meta data (although **not** in [the right format](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#http_1) for `uploadType=multipart`) which gets encoded as a multipart request.

Google is taking the whole multipart request and saving the whole thing as a single file (because that is what you told it to expect).

Answer (score 0):

The simple upload method (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#simple) consists basically of:

1. Create a `POST` request using the `/upload` URI with query parameter `uploadType=media`
2. Add the file's data to the request body (*raw data* from file)
3. Add `Content-Type` header. Set to the MIME media type of the object being uploaded.
4. Add `Content-Length` header. Set to the number of bytes you upload.

So the second step is missing in this case. You need to set the file object as the `body` value (instead of `formData` you created):

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: fileInput.files[0], // here
  redirect: 'follow'
};
```

Also you can use the file size from the input

```
myHeaders.append("Content-Length", fileInput.files[0].size);
```

Comment: Hi Igor.

Im a complete noob in Javascript though. How do you add the 'file raw data' on the spot that says (// here)?

Comment: Hey @gniffe, just as it's written there: `body: fileInput.files[0],` should work  (assuming `fileInput.files[0]` is your file input element as in your code example)

Comment: Hi Igor. Yes, that is exactly the problem. I think I am not successful yet in getting my file to be the file input element called fileInput.files. How do I do that?